# Can't use plugins in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to manage cookies in the browser and use this external plugin vue-cookies.
But if I call its method in some vue file as this.$cookies.get(...) I get an error in the browser:
`TypeError: Cannot set property '$cookies' of undefined`

Here is my code.
Main.js

```
    import App from './App.vue'
    import router from './router'
    import VueCookies from 'vue-cookies';
    import { createApp } from 'vue'
    const app = createApp(VueCookies)
    app.use(VueCookies);
    createApp(App).use(router).mount('#app')
```

App.vue (or any other .vue file)

```
beforeMount() {

    var cookie = "";
    cookie = this.$cookies.get("testname");
    console.log(cookie);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of v1.7.4, `vue-cookies` only works with Vue 2.

Vue 3 requires [`vue3-cookies`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue3-cookies) instead:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueCookies from 'vue3-cookies'

createApp(App)
  .use(VueCookies)
  .mount('#app')
```